# ReSharper: Highlighting in Tooltips

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, visual-assist

Does ReSharper have the option to highlight text in tooltips? Like in [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/default.asp):

[image]

It increases readability significantly, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened! Our prayers have been answered!

Meet [**ReSharper.EnhancedTooltip**](https://github.com/MrJul/ReSharper.EnhancedTooltip) by [**Julien Lebosquain**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183367/julien-lebosquain).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer the question to 100% but what I can say is, that I use JetBrains products since 2009 and I saw never a feature like this.

Maybe there is a custom plugin which enriches the tooltips with a highlighting.

It would be a great feature. :)

Regards,
- Tobbo

Comment: It is too great to be unreleased yet. I suspect there are reasons for that.

Comment: It could lead to a "lsd"'ish looking help. I mean, a tooltip should not distract from the source. Hm...

Answer (score 1):

Suggested on JetBrains tracker: [Highlighting in Tooltips](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-387440)
Please, vote for this feature there.
Or discuss here: [Highlighting in Tooltips](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5500030#5500030)

**Update**
Also vote for new very useful feature [Syntax Highlighting everywhere](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-397233)